# Table variable not working in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

My trigger  is as below ,

```
Alter TRIGGER [dbo].[LogTable_InsertTrigger] on [dbo].[std_table]  AFTER  INSERT
as

    DECLARE  @ColName varchar(50), @QueryText nvarchar(max)

    declare @inserted  TABLE(
      [CountryID] [int] NOT NULL,
      [Country] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
      [RegionId] [int] NULL
    )
    insert into @inserted
    select * from inserted

    DECLARE objCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    select  ColName from dbo.getColumnNames('std_table')  

    OPEN objCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM objCursor INTO @ColName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
      set @QueryText= '
         insert into dbo.LogTable
         (StandardType,Attribute,Action,NEwValue,UserId,ModifiedDate)
        select ''Country'','''+@ColName+''',''Insert'','+@ColName+',1,getdate()
        from @inserted'

       EXEC sp_executesql   @QueryText  

       FETCH NEXT FROM objCursor INTO @ColName
    END
    CLOSE objCursor
    DEALLOCATE objCursor
```

When I try to insert to table std_table in DA Layer I get the exception `Must declare the table variable "@inserted"`.

I couldn't use the inserted table directly because I am writing a dynamic query, inside which magic tables wont work. So I am trying to dump the data in inserted table to a temp table and to access from that.

I tried with

```
select * 
into #inserted
from inserted
```

This works, but since my application is accessed by many users over network this will cause data issues. So I can't use this.

Comment: cursor in a trigger: you are going to TSQL hell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things wrong here.

1. That is a table variable, not a user defined table type.
2. If #temp tables work, why do you think that will cause data issues for multiple users? Each user will get their own version of the #temp table.
3. If you know there are exactly three columns and you can hard-code the table variable declaration, why do you need to then generate the three sets of inserts dynamically? Aren't the column names `CountryID,Country,RegionID`?

If you really need to do this dynamically then it seems like you could do this an easier way without an explicit cursor - not that this is necessarily a bad thing or that it will perform any worse than the below, but the cursor is just much more verbose and ugly code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[LogTable_InsertTrigger] 
ON [dbo].[std_table]  
AFTER  INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT * INTO #t FROM inserted;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @sql = N'';

  SELECT @sql = @sql + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'INSERT INTO dbo.LogTable
        (StandardType,Attribute,Action,NewValue,UserId,ModifiedDate)
        SELECT ''Country'','''+ColName+''',''Insert'','+ColName+',1,GETDATE() 
     FROM #t;'
  FROM dbo.GetColumnNames('std_table');

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

Comment: 3. My tables has more than three columns . and this same query will repeat for 20 tables which all together will have around 200 + columns

Comment: Well that sounds like a design disaster, but the above trigger should work for any number of columns (assuming the function is accurate and all of those columns actually do exist in `inserted`). You might consider change tracking or creating a shadow table that matches the primary table so that you can perform 1 insert instead of 200.

Comment: I coudn't do like wat you said . I get error as "Invalid object name 'inserted'"

Comment: Hmm, appears like a scoping issue. How often does the schema for `std_table` change?

Comment: schema wont change . but i need to insert each columns of std_table to log table separately . Each column name and value should be inserted to log during each insert to std_table.

Comment: I've updated the code sample with a #temp table-friendly version. Please try it.

Comment: thanks a lot . trigger works perfectly alright. But I have a question . In code no where we dropped #t  .but still it never gives error in successive trigger execution . and even I couln't find this table in Temporary Tables of tempdb . May I know how ?

Comment: You don't have to explicitly drop #temp tables (but you can if you wish after `exec sp_executesql`), since they automatically go out of scope at the end of execution. The reason you might not want to drop it is because the metadata can be reused in tempdb. I haven't proven or disproved this, but if it is true, you'll want to use a more distinct name than `#t` in each separate trigger, e.g. `#std_table`.